# XAML Header text missing when phone preview orientation change to horizontal and extra margin for absolute layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have this Xamarin XAML which have a background image with header text and 3 button overlay at the bottom. Second how do I remove the extra margin between the 3 buttons?

```
        <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="Flower.jfif" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="0,20">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <Label Text="Relax" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#66000000">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <Button Text="Profile" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Button Text="Meditate" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Button Text="Theme" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XAML Header text missing when phone preview orientation change to
>   horizontal

This is caused by the margin(Margin="0,20") you set :

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="0,20">
```

**Solution**:

Remove the margin and give a Y(here I use 0.05) to ViewControls like:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.05,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
```

> extra margin for absolute layout

There is a [default space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms#property-value) of stacklayout, the default value is 6.0.

**Solution**: you can add a `spacing = -6` to remove it:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Spacing="-6">
```

Here is the full code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image Source="Flower.jfif" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.05,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <Label Text="Relax" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControlss" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#66000000">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Spacing="-6">
            <Button Text="Profile" BackgroundColor="Yellow" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Button Text="Meditate" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Button Text="Theme" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```